# Microsoft TestServer fails requests in NUnit/.Net Core on TFS 2018 build task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, integration-testing, tfsbuild

I have set up some API integration tests using a .NET Core 2.2 console app and NUnit 3. The API project uses .NET Core 2.2 as well, and everything is configured, building and running just fine.

However, the integration tests do not work when built out to TFS 2018. The `dotnet test` task in the TFS build works fine for all my unit tests, but any test written using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer` library to make requests to the API, fails with a `500`.

API Controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AppController
{
    [HttpPost("bootstrap"), ActionName(nameof(GetApplicationBootstrap))]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(AppConfig), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(401)]
    public ActionResult<AppConfig> GetApplicationBootstrap()
    {
        return Ok(new AppConfig
        {
            IsAdministrator = true
        });
    }
}
```

Integration Test:

```
public class TestFixtureBase
{
    internal HttpClient Client;
    internal TestServer Server;

    [SetUp]
    protected void SetUp()
    {
        Server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseEnvironment("Development").UseStartup<TestServerStartup>());
        Client = Server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Post_WhenCalled_ReturnsAppConfigModel_Ok()
    {
        //Arrange
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "/app/bootstrap");

        //Act
        var result = await Client.SendAsync(request);

        //Assert
        Assert.True(result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }

    [TestCase("GET")]
    [TestCase("PUT")]
    [TestCase("DELETE")]
    public async Task Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAppConfigModel_Error(string method)
    {
        //Arrange
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method), "/app/bootstrap");

        //Act
        var result = await Client.SendAsync(request);

        //Assert
        Assert.False(result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, result.StatusCode);
    }

    [TearDown]
    protected void TearDown()
    {
        Server = null;
        Client = null;
    }
}
```

Test Results Locally:

[image: Resharper results]

[image: dotnet test results]

Test Results on TFS:

[image: Build task test]
[image: TFS results]

The same tests run, with the same command locally, `dotnet test` and for every integration test when run in the Build task, I get `InternalServerError` instead of `MethodNotAllowed`.

Am I missing some configuration settings on the build server? Does the agent need to be set up differently? I have VS2017 Enterprise with the latest updates and IIS turned on across the board on the server. Is the build agent not capable of setting up a `TestHost` like my local workstation is?  What is the difference between me running `dotnet test` locally, and the Build Agent running the same command?

Any clues to this mystery are greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTTP 500 = unhandled exception. Throw an exception when you get a 500 so you can see what actually happened